# How to save to some data to database after order has been placed

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I am new to magento 2. I am trying to add observer that will be triggered after order has been placed.

I have save some certain data to the cookies on my magento 2 website, i have intention to save it to database after the order has been placed already have the table created on the database. Just wanted it and some order details save to database when order has been placed

Comment: User event `checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`checkout_onepage_controller_success_action`**  is the best event if you have placed order from frontend.

This event is fire **`when we customer place an order and goes to  order success page`** .

This event give us order id of current place order of a customer and  then at observer using order interface you can get order details.

```
<?php
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;

class [ClassName] implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_order;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface $order
    ) {
         $this->_order = $order;    
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
      $orderids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds();

        foreach($orderids as $orderid){
            $order = $this->_order->load($orderid);
        }
    }

}
```